# Modulo operation with decimals?

Tags: math, modulo

In System Dynamics there are transformations (like Arnold's cat map) in which, in addition to the iteration on the index  n, (mod 1) is applied. Example is:

```
Xn + 1 = 2 Xn (mod 1)
```

That for an initial value 0.65 we would obtain the sequence

```
(2x0.65) (mod 1) = 1.3 (mod 1) = 0.3
(2x0.3) (mod 1) = 0.6 (mod 1) = 0.6
(2x0.6) (mod 1) = 1.2 (mod 1) = 0.2
(2x0.2) (mod 1) = 0.4 (mod 1) = 0.4

That is: 0.65, 0.3, 0.6, 0.2, 0.4, .....
```

I do not understand which rule is applied, since I believe that A mod 1 = 0 for all A.
Can anyone say anything about the subject of this particular case?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question might be a better fit for [math.se]. They answer general questions about math; we focus only on programming-related questions. You might try asking there, instead.

Comment: My lack of experience. It's my first question
Thank you so much

Comment: No worries, and you're welcome. I hope you find your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here `x mod 1` means that you remove integer multiples of `1` to get the smallest possible result. That is, the fractional part of `x`.

In `C` you have, as example, the `fmod` function implementing this operation.

Comment: OK. This is a new definition of operation A mod B = R. Do you know which mathematical authorities have defined it and why?
The classical definition was "is the remainder of the integer division A \ B", as the integer division implies rounding of the factors, the result is an integer or zero.
Examples:69.7 mod 3 = 1; 69.4 mod 3 = 0; 69.9 mod 70 = 0;69.4 mod 70 = 69; 69.4 mod 1 = 0; etc. Thanks.

Comment: People found it useful, for instance to reduce the argument of `sin` by multiples of `2*pi`, thus they implemented it. Essentially `fmod(a,b) { q = floor(a/b); return a-q*b; }`. Thus `fmod(69.7,3)=0.7`, `fmod(69.9,70)=69.9`, etc.